# ruby on rails can't launch server on osx mountian lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, osx-mountain-lion

I am running mountain lion osx 10.8.3 and have been taking the Ruby on Rails 3 Essential Training on Lynda.com.

It was all going ok until I got to the part, within accessing the project I created, where I'm supposed to launch the server. The guy teaching the course on Lynda said the web server "WEBrick ships with rails," so I didn't need to install Apache or anything else and that we'd be using WEBrick for the class.

So, when I type in the command line (as instructed): rails server

I got this error:

**Could not find gem 'jquery-rails (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.**

I did "Run `bundle install`..." which looked to be going fine at first, but then got this error:

**Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/build_info/coffee-script-source-1.6.2.info
An error occurred while installing coffee-script-source (1.6.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install coffee-script-source -v '1.6.2'` succeeds before bundling.**

I'm a complete novice when it comes to command line stuff. I have a good background in web mostly from the front-end, and mostly with design, usability and not so much in code, but a general rough working knowledge of basic html, some css, etc. So, I have no clue how to "Make sure that `gem install coffee-script-source -v '1.6.2'` succeeds before bundling."

Any help/insight you could offer would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you don't have permissions to install gems on your machine. In particular, to the version of Ruby on your machine that lives in `/Library`. A common problem.

What I would recommend doing is using a Ruby management tool like [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/) to manage your Ruby installation. This would install a version of Ruby within your home directory and because its files will be owned by you, you will be able to install gems as you please.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Will see if I can even figure out how to try that (so new to this - may need to go buy Ruby on Rails for Complete Idiots. Let me know if you know of a site/tutorial that explains Ruby on Rails so a 5 year old could understand it. Ha. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

[RVM](http://www.rvm.io)  works well too, and is relatively easy to install on Mac OS X.

If you are not comfortable with the command line [Rails Installer](http://railsinstaller.org/) looks like it will set up everything for you, including RVM, although I have not personally tried it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to Ruby On Rails, I suggest this great book by Michael Hartl - [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book)

It teaches you everything form setting up rvm, git, and heroku, to building your own twitter from scratch. Its a great resource if you're just getting started and I'd suggest going through that entire book first. Best of all, its free.

Other than that, to answer your question, the reason you're getting the error messages is because using the system default version of ruby doesn't usually give you access to install certain gems. You'd have to do a bit of tweaking the path where your gems get installed. I wouldn't recommend using this version as it is old and most gems are starting to leave support for ruby version 1.8.

There's a few choices when it comes to installing new versions of ruby and I would recommend using a ruby version manager like `rvm` or `rbenv`. They are both great choices. Also, make sure to look into installing `homebrew` for all your command line package installing needs. It'll help when you have to install databases like `postgresql` and `redis`.

**Resources**

- [RVM Installation](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/)
- [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/)

Answer (score -1):

Just run:

> sudo gem install coffee-script-source